# Overlapping vertical spacing in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am currently trying to get the display

[image]

By doing this code, i was able to produce

```
\begin{gather}
   1 \uparrow 1 = {}^1 1 = 1 \nonumber \\
   2 \uparrow \uparrow 2 = {}^2 2 = 4 \nonumber \\
   3 \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3 = {}^{{}^{{}^3}} {}^3 3 = 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 = \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}}}}}}_{3^{3^3} \text{ threes}}\tag{14}\label{eq.14}
\end{gather}
```

[image]

Of course, this is still not the correct display, so i then tried to use an `array` environment and use negative `\vspace`, i got close, but not quite the perfect display. Here is the code for that

```
\[\begin{array}{c}
   \vspace{0.2cm}
   1 \uparrow 1 = {}^1 1 = 1 \nonumber \\
   \vspace{-0.3cm}
   2 \uparrow \uparrow 2 = {}^2 2 = 4 \nonumber \\
   3 \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3 = {}^{{}^{{}^3}}{}^3 3 = 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 = \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}}}}}}_{3^{3^3} \text{ threes}} \vspace{1cm}\tag{28}\label{eq.28}
\end{array}\]
```

[image]

I probably could tinker around with that, but I am pretty sure that a better method exists, so if anyone can help it would be very appreciated.

> PS: *If a better method exists to only get the equation tag on the last line instead using `\nonumber`, please let me know*

Edit: One of the comments suggested to use `\smash`, so i tried and the code gave

```
\begin{gather}
  1 \uparrow 1 = {}^1 1 = 1 \nonumber \\
  2 \uparrow \uparrow 2 = {}^2 2 = 4 \nonumber \\
  \smash{3 \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3 = {}^{{}^{{}^3}} {}^3 3 = 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 = \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}}}}}}_{3^{3^3} \text{ threes}}}\tag{14}\label{eq.14}
\end{gather}
```

[image]

So using `\smash` seem to have only worked to remove the vertical spacing, but it has *pushed* the line to the left...

Comment: use `\smash{.....}` around the power tower and it will hide its height completely

Comment: You can use `\begin{equation} \begin{gathered}[b] …… \end{gathered} \end{equation}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle using `\smash` does help to remove the vertical space, but the problem is that the centering seems kind of off to the left...

Comment: @Bernard I tried to use `\begin{equation}\being{gathered}[b] ... \end{gathered}\end{equation}` and it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: you have not provided an example that anone can run to see any centering (the use of \nonumber` with `array` in your second fragment looks very odd by the way). It always makes a question clearer if it contains an example that shows the problem, not just fragments that can not easily be tested.

Comment: not really related to the tex question but why do your first examples have powers going to the left, but the final example have them going to the right?

Comment: that said your final example appears to have all three rows centred your first image showing the desired layout is neither aligned nor centred it is not clear what position you are using for the last line: it is clearly not centred if the first two lines are centred.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i am very new to all of the stack exchange, and i don't really know how to do what you said. I tried to make the question as clear as possible using fragments, but i don't know how to make it so the people can test it. If you have the time the explain i would appreciate it.

Comment: see mico's answer, the code blocks are all complete documents from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` but even without that just looking at the images the last one you show has all three lines centred, so it is not clear what you mean by "pushed left"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i understand what you meant. I will make sure to do so in the futur, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote,

> If a better method exists to only get the equation tag on the last line ..., please let me know.

I think you need a combination of an `equation` environment, an `aligned[b]` environment, and a `\smash[t]{...}` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq.14}
\begin{aligned}[b] % 'b' means "place equation number on bottom line"
   1 \uparrow 1                  &= {}^1 1 = 1  \\
   2 \uparrow\uparrow 2          &= {}^2 2 = 4  \\
   3 \uparrow\uparrow \uparrow 3 &= 
     \smash[t]{ {}^{{}^{{}^3\!}} {}^3 3 
   =   3 \uparrow\uparrow 3 \uparrow\uparrow 3 
   =   \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}}}}}}_{3^{3^3}\text{ threes}}
     }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's an additional solution, which (a) employs an `alignedat` environment to perform alignment on both the first and second instance of `=`, (b) changes the math status of `\uparrow`, `\uparrow\uparrow`, and `\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow` to `math-bin` (the default math status is `math-rel`), and (c) implements @egreg's suggestion to provide a bit more distance between the rows and to enlarge the contents of the `_{...}` component of the `\underbrace` directive in row 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq.14}
\addtolength\jot{4pt}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{2} % 'b' means "place equation number on bottom line"
   1 \mathbin{\uparrow} 1                  &= {}^1 1 &&= 1  \\
   2 \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow} 2          &= {}^2 2 &&= 4  \\
   3 \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow} 3 &= 
     \smash[t]{ {}^{{}^{{}^3\!}} {}^3 3} 
   &&=   \smash[t]{3 \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow} 3 \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow} 3 
     =   \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^{.^{3}}}}}}}}}}_{\mathclap{\textstyle 3^{3^3}\text{ threes}}}
     }
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main idea is the same as [Mico's about smashing the top of the big object](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583355/4427), but with some improvements on spacing and size of characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hyop}{m}
 {
  \mathbin{ \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \uparrow } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\preexp}[2]{\vphantom{#2}^{#1}\kern-\scriptspace#2}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq.14}
\begin{aligned}[b] % 'b' means "place equation number on bottom line"
   1 \hyop{1} 1 &= \preexp{1}{1} = 1  \\
   2 \hyop{2} 2 &= \preexp{2}{2} = 4  \vphantom{\preexp{\preexp{3}{3}}{3}}\\
   3 \hyop{3} 3 &= \preexp{\preexp{3}{3}}{3}
   = 3 \hyop{2} ( 3 \hyop{2} 3 )
   = \smash[t]{
       \underbrace{
         3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{3}}}}}}}}}
       }_{\text{$\displaystyle 3^{3^3}$ threes}}
     }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]